# Using Navbar fixed-top and keeping container below it fixed to its bottom even upon scrolling?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

[image]I am using “navbar fixed-top” from Bootstrap. And underneath it I have a container. What I noticed is whenever I scroll down the page, the container underneath the navbar starts to slide below the navbar (refer to attached photo). I am aware that this is an expected behaviour with fixed-top, but I am wondering is there away to always keep the container below the navbar fixed to its bottom even when the user scrolls down?

[image]

Comment: You may add a padding-top to <body> element.

Answer (score 0):

Get the height of your fixed element, let's say 50px, and then:

```
body {margin-top:50px}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, this fixed the issue to me when the page loads up. However when I start scrolling down the page the container still does slide underneath the navbar.

Comment: So you want your container to cover fixed element, on scrolling ? Maybe you want to hide fixed element when scrolling start ?

Comment: Please refer to the newly added image, which I hope explain what I would like to achieve. Basically when I scroll down I do not want the container to start to disappear from the very top of the window, but from the bottom line of the navigation bar.

Comment: For this you would need some jquery. If you dont want to use js, just remove fixed position on top, and then it will scroll normally.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the header height as the margin-top of the container.. for example..

**css**

```
.container {
 margin-top:100px; /*height of the header*/
}
```

OR

**JQUERY**

```
var headerheight = jQuery('header').outerHeight();
jQuery('header').css("margin-top",headerheight);
```